# Does the phrase "pass out" also mean "to graduate"?

Tags: phrases, british-english, subcontinental-english

I'm from India and the phrase `Pass Out` is widely used here  to imply graduation. Googling as well as asking teachers keeps giving me mixed opinions.

So, is this usage actually correct?

Comment: I've never heard this usage, but Josh's answer shows it has some currency, at least in BrE military contexts.  However, if the usage were restricted to India (or is in some contexts restricted to India), that wouldn't mean it was  incorrect.  It would simply mean that it's part of the variety of English used in India.

Comment: Note that you should be careful about using this phrase if you go to America as "passing out" is used to describe losing conciousness after drinking too much.

Comment: In the UK it can also mean fainting whatever the circumstances.

Comment: Also intriguing: In idiomatic U.S. English, **pass on** can mean to transfer (in the sense of pass along), or it can mean to politely refuse, or it can mean to die.

Comment: ELU expects research results to be posted with questions, even (or especially) when the results are/seem contradictory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***To [pass out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/pass-out)*** is a BrE expression which means  to leave college after graduating, especially in military contexts. The idiomatic expression may have been adopted in India from the BrE usage:

> (uk) to leave a military college after successfully finishing the course:
>
> - *The new officers passed out from Britannia Royal Naval College on Thursday 1 August.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***[To pass out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pass-out):***

> - (INTRANSITIVE) (BRITISH) to officially complete a course at a military or a police college.

(MacMillanta Dictionary)

***[To pass out](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pass-out):***

> When a police, army, navy, or air force cadet passes out, he or she completes his or her training.[British]
>
> - *He passed out in November 1924 and was posted to No 24 Squadron.*

(Collins Dictionary)

Also, as suggested from the following extract from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Indians-say-passing-out-from-college-rather-than-graduating-from-college):

> - The Indian education system, has always followed British English mainly  because of the influence of British colonization in India before independence.
> - ***Pass out in British English means Graduate***. However in America, the term is commonly used to denote fainting; usually under the influence of alcohol. Grammatically and historically there is nothing wrong with using the term.

And from ***[Ten surprising expressions in Indian English](https://www.britishcouncil.org/voices-magazine/ten-surprising-expressions-indian-english)***

***'I passed out of college'***

> - When someone passes out, your first response may be to loosen their collar and get a cold towel. Fear not, in India, passing out has little to do with fainting or falling unconscious. ***It actually links to number one on the list. 'I passed out' from this college or that university is the Indian-English way of saying 'I graduated'.***

Comment: I don't think this answer sufficiently emphasises that in British English this is restricted to military college. I don't believe I've ever heard it for any other kind of institution.

Comment: @ColinFine - the military BrE usage is clearly stated in the dictionary definition I posted as the first source. I think it is very likely that the expression moved out from the military context when used in India.

Comment: the Cambridge quote says it, but the Quora one does not mention it (and I think is misleading for that reason). So I thought it was important to make the point. explicitly.

Comment: @ColinFine - I've added the information in my introductory note,

Comment: It's also worth noting that *pass out* as "faint" is the primary meaning in British English, and the "graduation" sense is secondary by a long way. I have no idea how the two senses compare in Indian English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - The "faint" connotation is cited in my answer, but how the two sense compare in Indian English is another interesting issue that may require further  research.

Comment: May I clarify @Josh that if somebody faints we say they *fainted* or *became unconscious* in Indian English. 'Pass out' is not typically used to refer to fainting, so the 'graduation' meaning is certainly more common, as in "*the whole family attended his college passing-out ceremony.*" Nor is it restricted to a military college and is even used to refer to high school graduation: *"100 students have passed out from this school with excellent marks this year.*" A notorious error sometimes seen is to use *pass away* as in *"we are proud to announce that all our students passed away this year."*

Comment: Fascinating information. Thanks for sharing. I would also like to point out that in Malaysia (which is also a former British colony), "passing out" can also mean "graduating".